# Force JavaExec task up to date

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a custom Gradle task (extending `JavaExec`) that should use an incremental building to not be executed most of the time:

```
task printFoo(type: JavaExec) {
    inputs.dir ...
    outputs.upToDateWhen( { return true } );

    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = "mypackage.MyMain"
}
```

At first glance, this works fine: When I run the task twice, it runs only once. If I edit some of the input files, it will re-run.

The problem is: it will re-run every time I change *anything* in my source code. This makes sense because `JavaExec` has all my source files as input since a different program might do different things. But since it is a very large project most of the changes in the source code won't change anything in the outcome of this task. I thus do not want to re-run it if something changes in my code (maybe except for the main class, but it won't change anytime soon so this is optional).

Is there a way to achieve this behavior? I tried removing files from `inputs`, but apparently they are initialized after my code. I also thought about putting this task into `buildSrc`, but this has ugly implications on the dependencies of `MyMain` to the rest of the project.

Comment: Setting its classpath to the main runtime classpath means this task can't run until your main source set is compiled, which becomes stale when anything in `src/main/java` changes. Look into alternatives there. Perhaps you could split out this main method and other code into a separate subproject. Or, define a separate source set for this main method and whatever else depends on it and use that instead. Or move it to an entirely separate project, depend on it as a JAR in a custom configuration.

Comment: @piegames any solution for this?